# Calculation output isn't correct

Tags: c

As I am still new to c programming, I am having an issue with the output calculation in the program below.  When I input 2.8 as the total miles, 2 passengers, and 1 for Airport cab ride.
The total fare owed should be $8.04. The distance charge is 5.04 with a 1.00 surcharge for 2 passengers (there is no surcharge for the first passenger), and 2.00 for the airport. Right now, it just keeps printing the minimum fare of $5.00.  I am not sure what I have missed, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Annette

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MINFARE 5.00
#define FARERATE 1.80

int main() {
    //Declare all of the variables types and their data types and values as applicable.
    float totalFare, distance = 1.0;
    int numberOfPassengers, airport;
    float fare = distance * FARERATE;

    //Prompt passenger to enter the total distance (measured to 1/10 of a mile) with a keyboard
    printf("Please enter the total distance, ");
    printf("enter it measured to 1/10 mile, e.g. 25.5:  ");
    scanf("%g", &distance);

    //Prompt the user to enter the number of passengers
    printf("\nPlease enter the number of passengers: ");
    scanf("%d", &numberOfPassengers);

    printf("\nPlease enter the type of travel?  ");
    printf("Enter (1) for Airport cab ride and (2) for Non- Airport cab ride:  ");
    scanf("%d", &airport);

    /*Calculate the fare amount with the number of passengers, such that, the initial rider is charged the fare only,
    the first additional passenger charge is the fare plus $1.00 and additional passengers are charge an additional
    $0.50 per passenger*/

    if (airport == 1) {
        totalFare = fare += 2.00;
    }

    else {
        totalFare = fare;
    }


    if(numberOfPassengers <= 1) {
            totalFare = fare + 1.00;
        }
        else
            if(numberOfPassengers > 1) {
                totalFare = (fare += 1.00) + (0.50 * (numberOfPassengers - 1));
            }

    //Prints the user entered amounts
    printf("\nYou entered %g as the total miles, %d passengers, and %d for Airport cab ride.", distance, numberOfPassengers, airport);

    //Prints the $5.00 minimum fare amount for anything that calculates below $5.00.
    if (fare<MINFARE) {
        printf("\nThe total fare owed is:\t $%.2f", MINFARE);
    }

    else {
            printf("\nThe total fare owed is:\t$%.2f", totalFare);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing `scanf("%g", &distance)` after you do `fare = distance * FARERATE`. When you change a variable in C, it doesn't retroactively change past calculations you did with it.

Comment: Ok, so because it is a float fare = distance * FARERATE is variable data type, then I just need to change the scanf to scanf("%f", & distance); correct?  If  that is right, it still is printing the minimum of 5.00, can you see why?

Comment: @AnnetteKitz No, that's not right. Changing `%g` to `%f` has nothing to do with what I said.